# I can't minimize Thunderbird in Yosemite OS

Tags: thunderbird, osx-yosemite

I accidentally hit the green "maximize" button and now Thunderbird is full screen. I cannot find a way to minimize or make it smaller in any way. 
The minimize button is grayed out.

Anyone know what is going on or what I can do?
Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Try  moving cursor to the top edge of the screen which makes a visible menu bar along with the green full-screen button and red close button. Press the green button to exit out of full-screen.